# Can the verification performance be output from MNIST training data and test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch, mnist

```
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn.init
import torch.nn.functional as F
# from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier # Test i did
# from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(device)

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100

mnist_train = dsets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/', # Specify download path
                          train=True, # Specify True to download as training data
                          transform=transforms.ToTensor(), # Convert to tensor
                          download=True)

mnist_test = dsets.MNIST(root='MNIST_data/', # Specify download path
                         train=False, # If false is specified, download as test data
                         transform=transforms.ToTensor(), # Convert to tensor
                         download=True)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=mnist_train,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True,
                                          drop_last=True)

class CNN(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # l layer
        # ImgIn shape=(?, 28, 28, 1)
    
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))

        # 2 layer
 
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))

        # 7x7x64 inputs -> 10 outputs
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 100, bias=True)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 10, bias=True)


    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)   # Flatten for total bonding layer
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(out))
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

# CNN model definition
model = CNN().to(device)

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)    # Softmax function included in cost function.
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


total_batch = len(data_loader)
print('Number of batches : {}'.format(total_batch))

def epoch_acc():
    X_test = mnist_test.test_data.view(len(mnist_test), 1, 28, 28).float().to(device)
    Y_test = mnist_test.test_labels.to(device)

    prediction = model(X_test)
    correct_prediction = torch.argmax(prediction, 1) == Y_test
    accuracy = correct_prediction.float().mean()
    acc = accuracy.item()

    return acc

for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0

    for X, Y in data_loader: # I take it out in a mini-batch unit
        # image is already size of (28x28), no reshape
        # label is not one-hot encoded
        X = X.to(device)
        Y = Y.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        hypothesis = model(X)
        cost = criterion(hypothesis, Y)
        cost.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        avg_cost += cost / total_batch

    print('[Epoch: {:>4}] cost = {:>.9}'.format(epoch + 1, avg_cost) + " " + "ACC= ", epoch_acc())

# I will not proceed with learning, so torch.no_grad()
with torch.no_grad():
    X_test = mnist_test.test_data.view(len(mnist_test), 1, 28, 28).float().to(device)
    Y_test = mnist_test.test_labels.to(device)

    prediction = model(X_test)
    correct_prediction = torch.argmax(prediction, 1) == Y_test
    accuracy = correct_prediction.float().mean()
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy.item())
```

This code is the data separation of MNIST using CNN.

If you run this
During 15 epochs, the cost and learning performance (acc) are displayed.

However, I would like to output validation performance as shown in the figure here

[image]

The picture is also a code that uses this code.

Currently, in this code, training data is set as 60000 and test data is 10000. How do you output the validation performance here?

Can i find the validation performance( VallACC ) in the code itself?

Or Using a sklearn should I create a new validation set and use the same method as cross validation?

---

2021-04-26 This code was modified by adding the code you uploaded.

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn.init
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import (
    DataLoader,
    random_split,
    SubsetRandomSampler,
    WeightedRandomSampler,
)

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(device)

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100

mnist_train = dsets.MNIST(
    root="MNIST_data/",  # Specify download path
    train=True,  # Specify True to download as training data
    transform=transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert to tensor
    download=True,
)

mnist_test = dsets.MNIST(
    root="MNIST_data/",  # Specify download path
    train=False,  # If false is specified, download as test data
    transform=transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert to tensor
    download=True,
)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=mnist_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True
)


class CNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # l layer
        # ImgIn shape=(?, 28, 28, 1)

        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        )

        # 2 layer

        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        )

        # 7x7x64 inputs -> 10 outputs
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 100, bias=True)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 10, bias=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)  # Flatten for total bonding layer
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(out))
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out


# CNN model definition
model = CNN().to(device)

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)  # Softmax function included in cost function.
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


total_batch = len(data_loader)
print("Number of batches : {}".format(total_batch))

valid_size = 0.2
num_train = len(mnist_train)
indices = list(range(num_train))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
split = int(np.floor(valid_size * num_train))
train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    mnist_train, batch_size=64, sampler=train_sampler, num_workers=2
)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    mnist_train, batch_size=30, sampler=valid_sampler, num_workers=2
)

for i, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    # move tensor to gpu if cuda is available

    data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
    # clear the gradiant of all optimizer variable
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # forward pass: compute pradictions by passing inputs
    output = model(data)
    # calculate batch loss
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    # backward pass: compute gradiant of the loss with respect to the parameters
    loss.backward()
    # update parameters by optimizing single step
    optimizer.step()
    # update training loss
    train_loss += loss.item() * data.size(0)


# validate the model

model.eval()
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(valid_loader):
    # move tensor to gpu

    data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
    # forward pass: compute the validation predictions
    output = model(data)
    # calculate the loss
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    # update the validation loss
    valid_loss += loss.item() * data.size(0)

# calculate average loss
train_losses = train_loss / len(train_loader.sampler)
valid_losses = valid_loss / len(valid_loader.sampler)
scheduler.step()
# Print the train and validation loss statistic
print(
    "Epoch: {} \t Training Loss: {:.3f} \t Validation Loss: {:.3f}".format(
        epoch, train_losses, valid_losses
    )
)
# save model if validation loss decrease
if valid_losses <= valid_loss_min:
    print(
        "Validation loss decreased {:.4f}--->{:.4f}  Saving model...".format(
            valid_loss_min, valid_losses
        )
    )
    # save current model
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model_cifer.pt")
    valid_loss_min = valid_losses
print("Learning rate: {:.5f}".format(optimizer.state_dict()["param_groups"][0]["lr"]))
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using a data loader for the test/validation set? You can then calculate the accuracy for it at the end of every epoch much like how you do with the training set

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm still learning, so I just don't know. It would be nice if there was another way. What if I use it as a loader?

Comment: Most likely the training data was split to obtain a validation set. You would need to do something similar and create a separate loader for validation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split training data into 2 part for validation and training.

obtain training indices that will be used for validation

```
valid_size = 0.2
num_train = len(train_data)
indices = list(range(num_train))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
split = int(np.floor(valid_size * num_train))
train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]
```

define samplers for obtaining training and validation batches

```
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)
```

combine dataset and sampler to prepare dataloader.

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=64,
sampler=train_sampler, num_workers=2)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=30, 
sampler=valid_sampler, num_workers=2)
```

2.Use validation data for validate the model.After each epoch training loss and validation loss will be printed , and only parameters with minimum validation loss will be save.

```
    for i,(data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):       
        # move tensor to gpu if cuda is available
        
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        # clear the gradiant of all optimizer variable
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # forward pass: compute pradictions by passing inputs
        output = model(data)
        # calculate batch loss
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        # backward pass: compute gradiant of the loss with respect to the parameters
        loss.backward()
        # update parameters by optimizing single step
        optimizer.step()
        # update training loss
        train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

    
    # validate the model

    model.eval()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(valid_loader):
        # move tensor to gpu
        
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        # forward pass: compute the validation predictions
        output = model(data)
        # calculate the loss
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        # update the validation loss 
        valid_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

    # calculate average loss
    train_losses = train_loss/len(train_loader.sampler)
    valid_losses = valid_loss/len(valid_loader.sampler)
    scheduler.step()
    # Print the train and validation loss statistic
    print('Epoch: {} \t Training Loss: {:.3f} \t Validation Loss: {:.3f}'.format(epoch, train_losses, valid_losses))
    # save model if validation loss decrease
    if valid_losses <= valid_loss_min:
        print("Validation loss decreased {:.4f}--->{:.4f}  Saving model...".format(valid_loss_min, valid_losses))
        # save current model
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_cifer.pt')
        valid_loss_min = valid_losses
    print('Learning rate: {:.5f}'.format(optimizer.state_dict()['param_groups'][0]['lr']))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What does valid_size mean here?
and I tried running it accordingly, but it doesn't work.
for i, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader)
There is an error in the part  :’  :’

Comment: valid_size is represent how much size you want for validation from data,e.g.(0.1 or 0.2). and let me see the error you are facing so i can further help you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried combining my code with the code you uploaded. However, run-time errors are displayed. Why is that? Is the code wrong?  Let's add some code to this post!

Comment: RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: There is one more thing besides this, and the error message is long.. So I put my code back in the question. Look above!